# Netoffice Hello World

Tags: c#, developer-tools, netoffice

I used VSTO a couple of years ago with Visual Studio to do some nice little addins for outlook. But I can't justify the cost of VS to do some part time projects. As a result I have installed the free version of VS and downloaded a promising office addin tool called NetOffice.

I am ok at c# but can't find a hello world example that includes setting up the environment to work.

I have VS express installed but don't know what to do with the NetOffice assemblies etc to get a simple example working.

I looked through the documentation and found a reference to "Netoffice Developer Toolbox" which set up projects for people who are not using the full version of VS. That sounded like exactly what I was after so I downloaded that also.

When I run the app NetOffice.DeveloperToolbox.exe I get a lot of errors, it does eventually load but tabs are missing and nothing seems to work.

Start up error is:

> An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which
>   would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of
>   the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable
>   CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is
>   not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the
>   loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information. |
>   NotSupportedException | Void .ctor()

Following the link in the error message takes you to a page that has this description:

> If you were directed to this topic because of an error message in the
>   Visual Studio project error list or a build error, see How to: Use an
>   Assembly from the Web in Visual Studio.

I didn't know i was referencing anything in the web so don't know what to do next.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get NetOffice working or if they have found/written a tutorial to getting it sorted IE a hello world tutorial?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you find anything for starters, I am looking for some starting examples for Excel - Kindly let me know.

Comment: Found some examples as per the example below but it was step by step to get working I was looking for not code. after a few days playing around I got it going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try to start a .net assembly from a network location.
this is forbidden from net policies(normaly)
move the toolbox folder to your hd and everything is okay.

NetOffice contains examples/tutorials for each office product in the release package. you find a lot of example online too directly from the main page(netoffice.codeplex.com) anyway, NetOffice is a 1:1 wrapper, this means if you already know the office object model from VBA or PIA(VSTO), you are ready to use NetOffice(you can use existing PIA code in NetOffice).